# Converting incomplete date to datetime dtype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am importing csv file where date-corresponding column uses yyyymm format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LNcW.png)

first column represent the yearmonth
how can I convert it to the datetime object?

Comment: [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) takes a `format` argument, set it to [`"%Y%m"`](http://strftime.org/). Don't post data in images, please type it out in a reusable format.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated.